Amplify local lambda test: lambda function is missing its layer
I want to locally test a lambda function that uses a lambda layer.
This is my template:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      CodeUri: pathToFunction
      Layers:
        - !Ref MyLayer

  MyLayer:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion'
    Properties:
      LayerName: mylayer
      Description: My Lambda layer for payment handling
      ContentUri: projectRoot/amplify/backend/function/myLambdaLayer
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.8


When i do sam invoke local -e event.json MyLambdaFunction it says it cannot find the modules that are in the lambda layer.
On the cloud, testing the function works and I use the same layer. What is happening?
